# VBA tricky situation

Tags: excel, vba

I have two different TABS: OPERATIONS and DETAILS

**OPERATIONS:**

[image: image 1]

**DETAILS:**

[image: image 2]

Inside DESCRIPTION field there exist a 11-digit number which is the transaction number (i.e: **19278294999**).

DO NOTE that the same cell may contain more than one transaction (i.e: **19266048459 19299490755**).

I want to achieve this:

1. VBA SHOULD FIND EVERY TRANSACTION INSIDE "DESCRIPTION" CELL FROM TAB "OPERATIONS". IN THIS CASE THE FIRST ROW CONTAINS ONE TRANSACTION, ROW 2 CONTAINS ONE TRANSACTION AND ROW 3 CONTAINS 2 TRANSACTIONS
2. IT SHOULD COPY THE NUMBER FROM TAB "OPERATIONS" AND PASTE IT INSIDE COLUMN "NUMBER" FROM TAB "DESCRIPTION" (only do this if it is FAC or REC, not a N/C) AND THEN, IT HAS TO DO THE SUMATORY IN TAB "OPERATIONS". TAKE A LOOK:

[image: IMAGE 3]

This should be the expected output after using the code:

[image]

I've tried something like this but i am getting a message error like "Object required"

```
Sub M_snb()
  sn = Sheet1.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
  sp = Sheet2.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
  ReDim sq(100, 4)
    
  sq(0, 0) = sn(1, 1)
  sq(0, 1) = sn(1, 2)
  sq(0, 2) = sn(1, 3)
  sq(0, 3) = "Operation_ID"
  sq(0, 4) = "Amount"
  n = 1
    
  For j = 2 To UBound(sn)
    st = Split(sn(j, 3))
    For jj = 1 To UBound(st)
      sq(n, 0) = sn(j, 1)
      sq(n, 1) = sn(j, 2)
      sq(n, 2) = st(0)
      sq(n, 3) = st(jj)
        
      For jjj = 2 To UBound(sp)
        If CStr(sp(jjj, 1)) = st(jj) Then Exit For
      Next
      sq(n, 4) = sp(jjj, 2)
      n = n + 1
    Next
  Next
    
  Sheet1.Cells(1, 8).Resize(UBound(sq), 5) = sq
End Sub
```

How would you solve this?

---

EDIT #1
[image]

[image]

---

EDIT #3

[image]

Comment: please can you show the sheets (tabs) as text because I can't visualise your images

Comment: Hey @Kendle , sorry. What do you mean, pal?

Comment: You appear being a newbie programmer, using variable and function names as `M_snb()`, `sq`, `sn` and some more. I advise you to use better names, that will automatically help you to read and understand your own code.

Comment: @Kendle i dont understand, pal. What do you mean?

Comment: I can see your images now. I've got an idea or two. I'll try to look after work.

Comment: @Dominique: Did you never hear about snb. He probably got ill advised by that guy.

Comment: Why VBA?  Depending on your version, seems like something that could be done with worksheet formulas.

Comment: Hey @RonRosenfeld thanks for replying. I'm kinda lost right now. What would you do?

Comment: I'd probably use Power Query, available in Excel 2010+.  But, if you have Excel 365, I might try to create a formula solution.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I need to make it work and i used VBA before and i thought it was better.  I do not have excel 365 but take a look. It is just 2 different tabs, starting at column 'A' both of them.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld How can i share a spreadsheet in here in the comments area?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld take a look, i have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using VBA:
Although you mentioned in your instructions regarding `N/C` in the Type column, that did not seem to make any difference in your pictured results.  So it's not in my code, but, if needed, you should be able to add the logic easily enough.

Note that I used Regular Expressions to extract the relevant id numbers from the description column in the first table.
I also did the "work" in VBA arrays, as that is much faster than accessing the worksheet repeatedly.

```
Option Explicit
Sub M_snb()
    Dim vOps As Variant, vDets As Variant
    Dim rOps As Range, rDets As Range
    Dim re As Object, mc As Object, m As Object
    Dim I As Long, K As Long
    Dim vSum, vNumber
    
    
'initialize regex
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(?:\D|\b)(\d{11})(?:\D|\b)"
    End With
    
'read data into variant array for faster processing
'also set the ranges for when we write the results back
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Operations")
    Set rOps = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    vOps = rOps
End With
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Details")
    Set rDets = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    vDets = rDets
End With

For I = 2 To UBound(vOps, 1)
    vOps(I, 4) = 0
    If re.test(vOps(I, 3)) = True Then
        Set mc = re.Execute(vOps(I, 3))
        For Each m In mc
            For K = 2 To UBound(vDets, 1)
                If m.submatches(0) = CStr(vDets(K, 1)) Then
                    vOps(I, 4) = vOps(I, 4) + vDets(K, 2)
                    vDets(K, 3) = vOps(I, 1)
                End If
            Next K
        Next m
    End If
Next I

'rewrite the tables
    
    With rOps
        .ClearContents
        .Value = vOps
    End With
    
    With rDets
        .ClearContents
        .Value = vDets
    End With
                    
                
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, Ron.
I'm checking it out, stay sharp! :)

Comment: Ron, take a look. I have updated my question. It should display N/A because 19266048459
19299490755
correspond to B0001100005445 which is type N/C. Do you understand?

Comment: @new_programmer As I wrote, you can easily add that logic.  What happened when you tried?

Comment: Ron, i'm a little confused about your code. How would you add that condition?

Comment: @new_programmer On the line where you write the number into the details array.  Merely check to see what's in the Type column of the operations array before you write.

Comment: Hey Ron, how are you?
I have been playing with this problem a little bit. Could you please take a look at this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71216052/trying-to-make-some-weird-things-with-vba-strange-situation
I am kinda confused and i'd like to see your view